# Change WPF Button Foreground when the "IsMouseOver" is True

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, button, styles

I have seen a few similar questions but not of the solutions seem to work.

I would prefer to have the solution through XAML but wouldn't mind it through code (VB.net) either.

I have this code currently, not sure how much of it is correct:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkSlateGray"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="White">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your xaml is mostly correct exept of one thing. <Border Background="White"> should be <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">. Same goes for foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally correct. But do note that your `ContentPresenter` in your template has no `Content` property defined. Of course, if you need more complicated triggers, you can also combine with other things like `IsEnabled` into a `MultiTrigger`.

Comment: Thanks, with this input i have got what i wanted